# Attempting to get results from array sum

Tags: java, arrays

I want to create a program with the following objectives.

1. Inside the main method,

1.1.    Declare a two dimensional (10 x2, ie. 10 rows and 2 columns) integer array and populate it with random integers.

1.2.    Create an object of the ArraySum class.

1.3.    Pass the array in Step 1.1 by calling Summation (int [][] myArray)

1.4.    Print the return value of Summation (int[][] myArray)

2. Inside the Summation(int[][] myArray) method:

2.1.    Calculate the summation of all the elements in myArray.

2.2.    Return the summation.

So far I have this code.

```
public class ArraySum { 

    public int Summation(int[][] myArray) {

      int sum = 0;

      int num = 0;

       for( int num : array) {
          sum = sum+num;
         }

         return sum;
        }   
    public static void main (String[] args) {   

   Summation summation = new Summation();


   int sum = 0; 

   int[][] myArray = new int[][] {
   {1, 2},
   {3, 4},
   {5, 6},
   {7, 8},
   {9, 10},
   {11, 12},
   {13, 14},
   {15, 16},
   {17, 18},
   {19, 20}
   };

   Sum = Summation(int[][] myArray);

   return Sum;

    }
}
```

I'm getting two errors resulting from the myArray class missing, apparently. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I advice to generate random integers using new Random().nextInt();.
An 2dim array is sth like an 1dim array of 1dim arrays, so when You want to iterate throw it You need use two loops.

Comment: So what is **your** question?

Comment: Oh! I totally forgot! Sorry. I'm getting two errors regarding a missing class for myArray. I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class HelloDate {

    public static int Summation(int[][] myArray) {

        int sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray[0].length; j++) {
                sum += myArray[i][j];
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] myArray = new int[][] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 }, { 9, 10 }, { 11, 12 }, { 13, 14 },
                { 15, 16 }, { 17, 18 }, { 19, 20 } };

        int sum = HelloDate.Summation(myArray);

        System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

Please refer this code:

1、`public static void main(String[] args)` you can't return any value from this method.

2· for 2D array, you need use for loop to access each element.

3、`Sum = Summation(int[][] myArray);` is wrong, when you call a method, you just need pass a paramter.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the thorough explanation.